# how to do partially match variable with array in python

Tags: python, arrays, comparison

I have a script to do a partial match variable with array but it is not working

```
import re

b = "Arun"
links_check_arr = ['Arun sdsdds',"dsds","arun ijiji"]
for links_find in links_check_arr:
    if b in list(links_find):
        print  links_find
        print b
```

Above script is not working

But if i remove list from if block it works as expected but it also matches empty values

```
import re

b = "Arun"
links_check_arr = ['Arun sdsdds',"dsds","arun ijiji"]
for links_find in links_check_arr:
    if b in links_find:
        print  links_find
        print b
```

output:

```
Arun sdsdds
Arun
```

But if i change b value to empty it also matches empty values

import re

```
b = ""
links_check_arr = ['Arun sdsdds',"dsds","arun ijiji"]
for links_find in links_check_arr:
    if b in links_find:
        print  links_find
        print b
```

Output:

```
Arun sdsdds

dsds

arun ijiji
```

But i dont want to match it with empty values

I want to do a partial match of "Arun" with list of elements in array ["Arun sdsdds","dsds","arun ijiji"]

Expected output:

```
input:

Arun
Output:

Arun

input:
A
Output:
"" -> (null)

input:

output:
```

How can i do it?

Comment: why don't you check if `b` is empty before going in the loops?

Comment: `if b in list(links_find)` - why are you calling `list` on `links_find`?

Comment: What's wrong with your second example? Isn't that the output you want?

Comment: What is your expected output supposed to be? What does 'partial match' mean?

Comment: Thats what i am expected but if i remove arun and give a it is also match which is wrong @Ulisha

Comment: @sidney if i give input as "Arun" Then output shoud be "Arun" if i give input as "A" then it should not give any output

Comment: So you want to b to match full words inside any of the strings?

Comment: Yes exactly @Ulisha

Comment: If that's the case, @sidney solution is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your first example, I think you're looking for `.split()` instead of `list()`.

```
for links_find in links_check_arr:
    if b in links_find.split():
        print  links_find
        print b
```

I'm assuming what you're looking for is similar to checking if `"Arun"` is a word within a list of strings.

A neater way to approach this problem would be to create a new list containing all the elements in `links_check_arr` containing your desired word. You can do this using:

`list_of_words = list(filter(lambda x: b in x.split(), links_check_array))`

where `b` is the word you're searching for (e.g. `"Arun"`), and `links_check_arr` is the list you're searching through.